# compare 2 dates, without considering the day

Tags: mysql, date

I need a SQL query to compare 2 dates based on their year and month only.

I.e. one date is 2017-07-12 and the second date is 2017-07-30.

Since they both share same month and year, I need to get them in my WHERE query.

I know how to do it with DATEFORMAT (converting both to the form of yyy-mm-01). I would like to know if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Show us the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare their month and year using the `Month()` and `Year()` functions:

```
WHERE YEAR(date1)=YEAR(date2) AND MONTH(date1) = MONTH(date2);
```

Some good information on the [mysql date and time functions page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in their manual.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL function [`EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) can be used for this purpose:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date1) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date2)
```

---

`EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2017-07-12')` returns `'201707'`.